# Why does Perl delete file content when used with find?

Tags: linux, bash, perl

Can anyone see why Perl deletes all file content when it is used together with `find`?

```
echo stning >> test.tex
echo stning >> test.tex
find . -type f -name \*.tex -print0 | xargs -0 perl -i -ne 's/stning/sætning/g' 
cat test.tex
```

The last command doesn't return anything, and that the issue.

Comment: @anubhava `find . -type f -name '*.tex' -exec perl -i -pe 's/stning/sætning/g' {} +` worked.

Comment: Why wouldn't you try it without `-i` first to check the output is correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need [`-p`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-p*), not [`-n`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-n*). The `-n` flag only reads, but doesn't print.

```
find . -type f -name \*.tex -print0 | xargs -0 perl -i -pe 's/stning/sætning/g'
```

You can easily remember this with the mnemonic *perl pie*, which is `perl -p -i -e` or shorter `perl -pi -e`.

Comment: It still deletes all content.

Comment: @JasmineLognnes show what you tried now in your question

Comment: The problem is that `-pi -e` makes far less sense that `-i -pe`. `-i` can be dropped without affecting the program, but `-p` is actually part of the program.

Comment: @JasmineLognnes I don't know.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve your result with sed itself. As just you need an inline replacement.

```
find . -type f -name \*.tex -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/stning/sætning/g'
```